# Multiple execution of Pexpect child

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

What happens if i launch same application using pexpect.spawn for unlimited times in Linux?
Pexpect.spawn("some continuously running programme")

Comment: Do they access/edit same chunks of memory eg. the same file?

Comment: Yes they do have